# Install only ubuntu on a hybrid drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have a windows 10 machine right now. I want to erase windows 10 and install ubuntu. The process is very easy in the installer, but I have a hybrid drive: 1 TB HDD and 256 GB SSD. What partioning should I do? How can I get the benefits of SSD in terms of speed and benefit of HDD in terms of storage? Please help

Comment: It depends on hardware. Does Ubuntu installer see the HDD and SSD as separate drives?

Answer (score 0):

The common and very often used approach is to use the SSD as the root filesystem and HDD as `/home` filesystem, which will be located on separate drive/partition.

You should use custom partitioning during installation (choose "Something else" option), select for example `/dev/sda2` as your root partition (you'll probably need `/dev/sda1` for the EFI partition), then add another mount point in the installer menu and add `/dev/sdb1` as the `/home` filesystem.

There are quite a lot of tutorials in the Internet on how to perform such installation on two drives, you should be able to easily find them with Google.